# jquery selectors for vector markup

Tags: jquery, vml

How can i access this tag using jquery selectors.

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
            <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:900px;height:600px;" id="x">
                <v:fill type="tile" src="myimg" color="#3b3b3b"  ></v:fill>
                <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
            <![endif]-->
<div style="opacity: 1;"></div>
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
            </v:textbox>
            </v:rect>
            <![endif]-->
```

I need to update the src attribute in the v:fill dynamically. I cannot figure out how to use a jquery selector to access this tag.

Is there anyway we could do this?

if you are wondering why i need to do this; am trying to generate html email template that is compatible with older outlook versions. The user is allowed to change this image by uploading one. When the user uploads the URL to src tag needs to be updated.

Update:
I could access the v:fill using $("v\:rect").find("v:\fill"). But the usual attr function doesn't work on this tag. Still working on it!
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you take a look at jQuery's [**Won't Fix page**](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/wiki/Won't-Fix#svg-or-vml) (updated May 2017), there's an entire section for VML, specifically [errors being thrown when trying to access attributes VML elements](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9807). Now, whether or not this is pertinent, or there's a workaround, I'm not familiar enough with VML to know - but worth pointing out nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks Tyler. I know i responded late. But i ended up using regular expressions.